# Unable to access samba file share

Tags: raspbian, networking, windows, file-server, samba

**Aim**

Trying to access Samba share from my RPi to all other machines within my LAN. If it's any help, my Samba version is 3.6.6.

**Problem**

The RPi is not showing up anywhere within the "Network" area of my Windows machines. I can not access the share by IP, either. However, I can of course ping both ways. I am greeted with the following message when I attempt to connect via IP:

> The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occured:
>   The account is not authorised for log in from this station.

Please see `smb.conf` file below.

```
[global]
   wins support = yes
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = no
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[sharename]
comment = USB Share
path = /mnt/disk1
writable = Yes
only guest = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = Yes
only guest = No
root@codaamok:/etc/samba#
```

**Note**

I have restart the Samba service, and I have tried `\\192.168.0.5\sharename`. I feel I am missing something very important within my config file, although this is hardly a modification from default (other than the `[sharename]`) which has worked before with no problem. If there is anything different between this time and the last, it would be that I actually upgraded to the latest wolfram-engine, whereas last time I didn't.

Also, /mnt/disk1 (including its parent) have `1777` permissions.

Comment: `192.168.0.5` looks suspicious, there should not be '0' or '255' in IP address.

Comment: I think 0's and 255's are acceptable IP address values. However, I solved the issue - added `security = user`. For some reason without this directive it did not enable me to see the share from Windows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can answer your own question, this will help others who may have the same problem. Also in the config posted above you have only guest = Yes and only guest = No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by not using the configuration file I used in my original post. I used the original (you can restore yours to default by copying a copy of the original from `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`) and made **two** modifications, detailed below:

```
####### Authentication #######

# "security = user" is always a good idea. This will require a Unix account
# in this server for every user accessing the server. See
# /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/ServerType.html
# in the samba-doc package for details.
   security = user

# You may wish to use password encryption.  See the section on
# 'encrypt passwords' in the smb.conf(5) manpage before enabling.
   encrypt passwords = yes
```

As you can see, I uncommented tag `security` attribute and flipped the value of the `encrypt passwords` from `no` to `yes` - this is a requirement if you wish to access your Samba share from a Windows machine (according to the manual, and my anecdotal experience obviously, hence why I've got it working.

Obviously, don't forget to include your share's attributes at the utmost bottom of the `smb.conf` file.

Comment: Nowadays the `encrypt passwords = yes` argument is not used by smbd and needs to be replaced with `smb encrypt = required`. You can check what valid arguments are being extracted from `smb.conf` by running `testparm`.

Comment: @sebpardo I have no doubt that things have changed since 6 years ago :-) click "improve this answer" or reply with your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by changing the following in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
dns proxy=Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sub.conf you have two entries for “only guest”